# how can i convert rgb value of pixel to HSV?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to find the R G B value of a pixel on the screen and convert this value, there is no problem except the conversion process.
Where am I doing wrong?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import cv2

s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 1152, 864))
for x in range(1,s.width):
    for y in range(1,s.height):
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        k = pyautogui.position()
        rgb = pyautogui.pixel(k[0], k[1])
        array = np.array(rgb)
        #hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(array,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) Not working.
        #hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(rgb,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) Not working.
        print(k,rgb,array)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: What output you're getting from hsv_frame ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
The code is generally failing due to the following possible reasons :

1. Your code do not have the type of array mentioned in the `np.array()` function.
2. The dimension of the array is also not the one which is opencv wanting for.
3. Pyautogui processes the image in RGB but the option is given to convert BGR to HSV.

This code should work fine now :

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import cv2

s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 1152, 864))
for x in range(1,s.width):
    for y in range(1,s.height):
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        k = pyautogui.position()
        rgb = pyautogui.pixel(k[0], k[1])
        rgb = [[rgb]] # increasing the dimension of array so that opencv can work with it
        array = np.array(rgb,np.uint8) # defining an array with uint8 type
        hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(array,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) # converting RGB to HSV
        print(k,rgb,array)
        print(hsv_frame)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Please do comment if further problem exists.

Comment: not working :((

Comment: Please see my edited code above. This should work fine now.